# Automatically using maximum column width in wxPython's HyperTreeList

Tags: python, listview, wxpython

In wxPython, there is a ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin which makes sure that the last column in the list uses up all the space available to the list, even when it resizes.

However, I have had problems with the native wxListCtrl on Windows that mean I want to use a different list, like the HyperTreeList that is new in 2.8.12.  This does not seem to have any easy way of doing what the ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin did.  Is there a way?  Is there an available mixin that I can use (I can presumably copy the existing mixin, but if someone has already done the work I would prefer to use that).

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the best answer would have been to use the UltimateListCtrl from the same library, which shares the same API.  However, this too seems to have problems.  Still investigating.